# What is block inside [[scope]] key and when it is created?

Tags: javascript, function, var, let

I tried the following code

```
let let_arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let_arr[i] = () => {
    return {
        let_i: i
    }
  };
}
console.log(let_arr);
```

and I found the block key exists when we use let in for loop.

```
[ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
  0: () => {…}
    arguments: (...)
    caller: (...)
    length: 0
    name: ""__proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: iif.js:26
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
        0: Block {i: 0}
        1: Script {let_arr: Array(4), var_arr: Array(4)}
        2: Global {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
```

While when using var
`for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` 
block element is missing.

```
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
    0: Script {let_arr: Array(4), var_arr: Array(4)}
    1: Global {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
```

Comment: it's under `Global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript functions are actually *closures*, that is, when you save a function somewhere, not only its code is retained, but also all variables available at the creation time. Variables are stored in dictionaries called *scopes*, which can be nested in each other ("scope chain").

In order to conserve memory, the engine only retains scopes that are actually used in the function. If a scope does not contain `let/const`, it is considered unused and omitted. If a scope does contain `let`, but that variable is not used in the function, it's also omitted. Otherwise the scope is retained and attached to the closure.

A couple of illustrations:

```js
var f

{
    var a
    f = () => a   // Global
}
console.dir(f)

//

{
    let a
    f = () => a
}
console.dir(f) // Block a + Global

//

{
    let a
    {
        let b
        {
            let c
            f = () => b  
        }
    }
}
console.dir(f)  // Block b + Global

//


{
    let a
    {
        let b
        {
            let c
            f = () => eval("b")
        }
    }
}
console.dir(f) // 'eval' retains everything
```

Comment: I also found Script {a:11} when I m learning from your answer. And the code is   
var f;

let a = 11;
f = () => a;
console.dir(f);

{
  let b;
  f = () => b;
}
console.dir(f);

What differs block and script sir?

Comment: @devumesh: almost nothing. `Script` is the top-level `Block`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour, because there are no variables in the block scope if you declare your variable with `var`. It's going to be hoisted up to the global scope in this case. You can read more about block scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).